# Changing background of TextBox when not in focus

Tags: c#, xaml, background, textbox, uwp

I have a TextBox in a XAML file that I want to change the background color of since the default color is grey when the box is not in focus. 
Changing the Background-property doesn't seem to work and I don't understand how to change it in the template.

This is how it looks now

[image: This is how it looks now]

And this is how I want it look

[image: And this is how I want it to look always]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to paly with the *TextBox's* style ([attached here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479922/2681948)). You will find there *BackgroundElement*, you can change its *Background* and *Opacity* for example like this:

```
<Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
```

This should give you foreground's color when control is in unfocused state, but you will also have to change Placeholder's color as it becomes invisible. Try also to play with *VisualStates* for apropriate states, including other than  focused/unfocused (normal).

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the template of control. The most convenient way to do this will be opening project in blend. Every control has its default template with visual states for common interactions like pressing, dragging etc.
Please look at this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170032.aspx 
I think it could be helpful for you.